# Using peerjs with Adobe InDesign

Tags: javascript, webrtc, adobe-indesign, peerjs

Hy,

I'm creating my own InDesign PlugIn and I need to connect to another web application I created. I tried using socket.io, but I didn't want to have another server, so I have passed to Peer JS, in this way I have a peer to peer system that would work perfectly, but I met some unexpected problems.

I'm working with Adobe InDesign CC, that uses CEP5, which has support for google chrome BROWSER (CEF (Chromium extended framework )).

In the Docs it's said that CEP5 has support even for WebRTC but when I try to connect with peerjs (wich uses WebRTC) to another peer I get a :"TypeError: undefined is not a function", under further investigation I discovered that the error is thrown by Object.Negotiator._startPeerConnection, but I can't understand what I'm getting wrong...

I tried using the same PEER JS code in another application(just a normal web site) and connecting to the same peer and was successfull, so I'm guessing that the problem is the in WebRTC support provided by InDesign.

I am not confined to using PEER JS, I just want my adobe plugin and my site to communicate in the most intelligent way possible, so any idea is welcome, however this is the piece of code of my plugin where I try to connect to the PEERJS

```
var peer = new Peer({key: mySecretKey}); 
var conn = peer.connect('editor-vaComeVibraEEE');//the exception is     generated here
conn.on('open', function(){
    conn.send('hi!');
});
```

Thank's for the help... . . .

Comment: Can you validate that navigator.webkitGetUserMedia and webkitRTCPeerConnection exist? Can you also share the peerjs log? Or the full stack trace?

Comment: ok, if i do an `alert(typeof navigator.webkitGetUserMedia)` inmy InDesign PlugIn I get undefinied, if I do it in my test app on chrome, I get a function object.

Comment: Can you do the same with navigator.getUserMedia? If it's also undefined then there is no WebRTC support. Maybe it should be explicitly enabled by switching some InDesign flag on?

Comment: I get undefinied there to, I'll check if I have to enable WebRTC support....

Comment: You should address your concern in the ExtensionBuilder Forum https://forums.adobe.com/community/creativesuites/extensionbuilder this is th adobe place for discussing exte,sion development.

Comment: @SvetlinMladenov there seems to be no flag to enable, should be already active...

Comment: @Loic thank's, I'll consider posting my question there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well,
the only solution I found was to abandon peerJS and migrate to [faye](http://faye.jcoglan.com/), which is  a publish-subscribe messaging system based on the Bayeux protocol. I think it's quite a good solution, and easy to implement. this is my server code

```
var http = require('http'),
    faye = require('faye');

var server = http.createServer();
bayeux = new faye.NodeAdapter({mount: '/'});

bayeux.attach(server);
server.listen(8000);
bayeux.getClient().publish('/inDesign', {
    text: val
});
```

and on the client side I receive the messages like so:

```
var client = new Faye.Client('http://localhost:8000/');

client.subscribe('/inDesign', function(message) {
  alert('Got a message: ' + message.text);
});
```

The server can receive messages from the client and teh client can write messages to the server in quite an easy way.

Hopefully this will help someone in the future.